# Closure around class constructor in ES2015 (ES6) classes

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6, closures

One can create a closure around the constructor function to hold, say, a unique ID for instances:

```
const MyObject = (() => {
  let id = 0;

  return function() {
    this.id = id++;
  };
})();
```

How would one achieve the same with classes syntax? Is there a way to create a closure around the class’s `constructor` function?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, using [class expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/class) you can do this:

```js
const MyObject = (() => {
  let id = 0;

  return class MyObject {
    constructor() {
      this.id = id++;
    }
  };
})();

console.log(new MyObject().id);
console.log(new MyObject().id);
console.log(new MyObject().id);
```

---

Or you can do it with regular class declarations too.

```js
const MyObject = (() => {
  let id = 0;

  class MyObject {
    constructor() {
      this.id = id++;
    }
  }

  return MyObject;
})();

console.log(new MyObject().id);
console.log(new MyObject().id);
console.log(new MyObject().id);
```

Comment: FYI, it is possible to wrap only the constructor by replacing the function on `MyObject.prototype.constructor` with a new one that references the original, but I think wrapping the entire thing seems cleaner.

Comment: Just FYI, you could even omit the name: `return class { ... }`.